# Loading template not displaying

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember data. I have a template, `loading.hbs` in my `/templates` directory.

My route for users looks like this:

```
renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
    this.render();

    this.render('settings.users.users', 
    { 
            outlet: 'users', 
            into: 'settings.users.index',
            model: this.store.find('user')
    });
}
```

I am testing this by putting a long sleep in my server code. I would expect the loading template to be rendered into `settings.users.users` but it's not.

Comment: What is the behavior you are currently experiencing? The template remains blank until the call from the server returns?

Comment: Yes, the the main template renders, however the template being rendered into the child outlets (users) is blank until the service returns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `loading.hbs` directly in your `templates` directory, you are saying that's the template that should be used when your `application` route is loading.

If you want this to be for a nested route, you need to nest it in your template directory appropriately (`/templates/settings/users/loading.hbs`, or something along those lines depending on the structure of your router).

Comment: Does that mean you must have many copies of your loading template? According to the [guides](http://goo.gl/y4tE50) it is sufficient to have one `loading` template or route.